# GLSL rewriting a branch

Tags: glsl

I'm curious how I can rewrite a branch into GLSL functions so that I can avoid the branch altogether.

```
if(uv.x > 0.0 && uv.x < 1.0 && uv.y > 0.0 && uv.y < 1.0 && uv.w > 0.0)
  compute value
else 
  value = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
float value = 0.0;
if( x > 0.0 )
    value = foo;
```

...could be rewritten to:

```
float value = 0.0;
value = foo * step(0,0, x);
```

Using this, you can combine all the checks into one single:

```
float value = 0.0,

x0 = step(0.0, uv.x),
x1 = 1.0 - step(1.0, uv.x),
y0 = step(0.0, uv.y),
y1 = 1.0 - step(1.0, uv.y),
w0 = step(0.0, uv.w);

float res_check = x0 * x1 * y0 * y1 * w0;
value = res_check * foo;
```

I hope you understand the concept how it works with `step` function.